# Applying increasing values to text field on focus or on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 18 rows of text fields and in each one I need to give it an increasing ID, however they're not just straight forward, as the bottom row in the grid could need ID 1 and the first one could need ID 15 depending on what is chosen. It doesn't need to look that pretty as long as it does the job. I will be using it to insert data in to a database from an iPad and ideally having an onclick event on the row title, and that adding the next incremental number would be perfect, however if that's not possible adding an onfocus event would be fine.

I already have the following

```
$('.played').on('focus', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.val() == ''){
        $this.val('1');
    } else {
      $this.val('');
  }
});
```

Which adds the number 1 in the clicked text field and if you click on it when it has the value of 1, it removes it. What I'd now like to do is when the next 'played' class text field that's clicked, it populates it with 2, and so on up to 18. Is this possible?

Comment: Put the last number assigned into a global variable. Every time you add a new field, you increment the number and use that.

Comment: I am actually just doing that as you replied, however, will it be a bugger to remove it if I remove the value?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Show your code, and explain what it's doing wrong and what you'd like it to do instead.

Comment: I was being a bit dumb... http://jsfiddle.net/e1kb6esm/ I added currentnum++ to increase the value, but didn't have currentnum-- to decrease it when the numbers were taken out, thus meaning it kept increasing! Think I was trying to overthink it!

Comment: I've got it working kind of how I need it to here http://jsfiddle.net/e1kb6esm/1/ However, if I add 7 or 8 values, then click to remove number 3, i'd like number 3 to be the next value, then go back to number 8 or 9 being the next value selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following to get the max value that you can check against yourself to know if you need to set it or clear it out, and additionally if you don't have a value and you do have a max value, your new value would be max + 1

```
var valueArray = $('.played').map(function(played){ return $(played).val(); }).toArray();
var maxValue = Math.max(valueArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've got it working kind of how I need it to here http://jsfiddle.net/e1kb6esm/1/ However, if I add 7 or 8 values, then click to remove number 3, i'd like number 3 to be the next value, then go back to number 8 or 9 being the next value selectable.

Comment: Oooh, now your getting tricky, lol.  In that case you'd have to have logic that checks your valueArray to see that all your numbers are present.  Starting at 1 until whatever.  If you don't find one you expect, you'd use that as your value instead of max + 1

Comment: I was just thinking I could check to see if the current number was different to the value being removed and if it was different then to save it as a different variable, however this would only work once, then the number would get lost.

Comment: I've got the following now http://jsfiddle.net/e1kb6esm/2/ where it stores the second number, i'm not sure how correct that is, but it works and stores a number!